# Problems to run node.js in a local network server

Tags: node.js, network-programming

I have created a simple node.js server example, running in my Debian server, at a local network.
It works when I access it locally, but doesn't when I use it's IP from other machine.

[image]

URL "http://192.168.2.220:3003" can't be found

I have other projects in this server, including a Apache at port 80.
Where is my mistake? 
Is something else needed to do for this work?

Below is the server example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('IT VORKS!\n');
}).listen(3003, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3003/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. check firewall settings.
2. use `.listen(3003, '192.168.2.220');` instead of `.listen(3003, '127.0.0.1');`

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept the answer, as it would be useful for others.